# Plaid Link Integration with React

Tags: reactjs, plaid

I have modified react-plaid-link to use create-react-class repo to support createReactClass. This is necessary because create-plaid-link loads up an iframe with the plaid "Banking Selection and Search" wizard.

I have it working kind of... it requires two clicks of the react link button to instantiate the iframe (the first click instantiates it and then removes it).  Has anyone else had this problem?    No doubt I can get around this issue by creating an artificial event to click the button twice but that is a hack of the first order.

Also is there anyone who has access to the react components that are rendered in the iframe by plaid?  This proprietary javascript UI nonsense that Plaid is attempting to foist on its developers is really tiresome.

Comment: solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257260/react-plaid-component-refreshes-the-page